# Sum of two divergent sequences with different number of partial limits

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Suppose that $(a_n)$ is a sequence which has $1050$ partial limits, and $(b_n)$ is a sequence which has $2750$ partial limits. I'm asked to prove that $(a_n+b_n)$ diverges.

So, in general the sum of two divergent sequences need not be divergent. I believe that the sum diverges when the number of partial limits of $(a_n)$ differs from the number of partial limits of $(b_n)$. However I have no idea how to approach the proof. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose $a_n + b_n \to L \in \mathbb {R}.$ Let $M$ be any subsequential limit of $b_n.$ Then there is a subsequence $b_{n_k} \to M.$ Thus $a_{n_k} = -b_{n_k} + (b_{n_k}+a_{n_k}) \to -M + L.$ There are $2750$ possibilities for $M,$ hence for $-M + L.$ This shows $a_n$ has at least $2750$ subsequential limits, contradiction.

Comment: Great proof, thank you.